# psql query in ruby model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, psql

How to implement the following query in ruby model:

```
select * from outsources where folder_id = 28 and id != 44 and returned = false;
```

Here,how to access the current record id instead of a particular id

Here is the outsource model:

```
class Outsource < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Workflow

  workflow_column :status

  # constants
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :folder

  after_initialize :init_dates
  before_update :init_return_date

  validate :folder_availability, if: proc { |i| i.folder.present? }
  validates_presence_of :folder_id, :vendor_id

  scope :open_transactions, -> { where(status: [OUTSOURCED, FINISHED, CANCELED]) }

  workflow do
    state :outsourced
  end

  private

  def folder_availability
    errors.add(:folder_id, 'This folder is not available for outsource. Please review.') \
      if self.folder.completed? || self.folder.abandoned? || self.folder.canceled? || self.folder.closed?
  end

  def init_dates
    self.outsource_date ||= Date.today
  end

  def init_return_date
    self.return_date ||= Date.today
  end
end
```

Here current record is Outsource and Folder. In which same folder belongs to multiple outsources.I need to change the status from outsource to in-progress when all the outsourced folders returned value become true

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [ActiveRecord basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#read). It's *vital* to learn this when working with rails.

To your query, it would convert to:

```
Outsource.where(folder_id: 28, returned: false).where.not(id: 44)
```

Update:

Yes, you can replace the numbers with your variables. Rails even is smart enough to automatically get all of the `outsources` belonging to your `current_folder`.

```
current_folder.outsources.where(returned: false).where.not(id: current_outsource)
```

Comment: Here I need to use current record id instead of and 28 and 44. Can I use self.folder_id and self.id for current record.

Comment: What is the current_record? Did you set up a relationship between the models?

Comment: And yes, you can replace your numbers with variables

Comment: Here current record is Outsource and Folder. In which same folder belongs to multiple outsources.I need to change the status from outsource to in-progress when all the outsourced folders returned value become true

Comment: can you post your models to your question?

Comment: I given the model as per your suggestion